# Wordpress payment and registration

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is my problem, I have to create a wordpress site for sports association website, an athlete must register on the website to indicate his information to integrate his license .. and then choose the type of race to which he wishes to participate , So I want to integrate a System of payment by CB and Paypal, on the same registration page and list those who have already paid by exporting an excel file with all this information.

thank you

Comment: So do you have a question? :)

Comment: How can do that , and there is any extension ?